# Random and complete iteration that is scalable?

Tags: java, algorithm, collections, random

Suppose I have a list of lists, like this:

- [[a, b, c, d, e],
- [f, g, h],
- [i, j, k, l]]

So the outer list is size 3 and the inner lists are sizes 5, 3 and 4.

I need to get a random element of any of those inner lists, given each element an equally random chance. So I could write an algorithm that:

- generates a random between `0` and `totalListsSize (5 + 3 + 4) = 12`, for example `randomIndex 7`
- iterate through all lists and subtracts their size if it's bigger then their size, for example `randomIndex 7 - firstListSize 5 = newRandomIndex 2`
- returns the element in the next list, `randomIndex 2 in secondList = element g`.

The problem is that sequential selection must be complete and depleteable: **After 12 sequential selections in the example above, I must have selected each element once.**

Is there a way to do that that is scalable?

- without initializing all lists first and randomize the joined list
- if holding a boolean array of which indexes have been selected already, without having to iterate through that boolean array just to translate the generated `randomIndex`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Why don't you generate a permutation of all possible indices (in other words you shuffle the sequence [0,12) ). Then you know that you will hit all elements exactly once and in random order.

For efficient lookup you can keep the running total of the array's lengths. In your example: 0, 5, 8, 12. That way you can do a binary search to find any array by the "total index".

Comment: The binary search is a very good idea. I'd still have to initialize a list the size of the `totalListsSize` and shuffle it, but I don't think there's any way around that.

Comment: Of course you can trade speed for memory here. How many lists and items do you expect?

Comment: The outer list is a size of about 3 to 10. The inner lists are actually Iterators that can produce more than a `1000 000` items easily. But it's very common that after selecting only a `1000` items randomly, the algorithm finishes. On the other hand it could as well select all `1000 000` items: there is no way to know up front.

Comment: Then, I have an additional speedup for you: Don't generate the permutation in the beginning. Instead, use a hash-table to keep track of the indices that have been used. But after maybe 5000 items have been selected, you will probably need many many more. So only then you generate the whole permutation (of the remaining indices). This probablistic algorithms saves you fram generating the permutation with high probability.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you might create a set of possible indices, randomly select one of those, remove the selected one and access the corresponding object.

Alternatively, as you said, you could create a joined list and select from that one, removing any selected element.

Both approaches would require some initialization, but you'd have to do some book keeping anyways.

Another approach might be to store the selected indices in a set and after creating a new random index you could check if the new one is already in the "used" set. However, if you want to select a high percentage of the entire pool this approach would get slower and slower, since you'd more frequently get already used indices. For selecting only a few from a big list this approach might be better, since it doesn't require that much initialization and memory.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible to remove the elements from the lists as you "pop" them?

If so you could simply do that: just remove an element from the list when you select it, then subtract one from the total size before calculating the next index and repeat as needed.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the following:

- Store a list of lists of integers `mark` which remembers the selected elements per list
- Then, to determine which element corresponds to your `randomIndex` do:

  ```
  List<List<Integer>> mark    = // ... one mark list for each array
  E[][] lists = // ... the lists you want to select random elements from

  void selectAllElementsOnce( int totalElementCount ){
      Random r = new Random();
      for(int selected = 0; selected < totalElementCount; selected++){
          E element = this.elementForRandomIndex(r.nextInt(totalElementCount - selected));
          // do something with this element
      }
  }

  E elementForRandomIndex( int randomIndex ) {
      for(int i = 0; i < lists.length; i++ ) {
          if(randomIndex < lists[i].length - mark.get( i ).size()) {
              int j = 0;
              while(mark.get( i ).size() > j && mark.get( i ).get( j ) <= randomIndex) {
                  randomIndex++ ;
                  j++ ;
              }
              mark.get( i ).add( j, randomIndex );
              return lists[i][randomIndex];
          } else {
              randomIndex -= lists[i].length - mark.get( i ).size();
          }
      }
      throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
  }
  ```

The complexity of this solution is in O(numberOfLists + maximumListSize) for an implementation of the mark lists which provides element access in constant time (e.g. ArrayList). Notice that it is no product of both terms since only a single list is iterated over.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following class:

```
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.Random;

public class RandomPermuteIterator implements Enumeration<Long> {
    int c = 1013904223, a = 1664525;
    long seed, N, m, next;
    boolean hasNext = true;

    public RandomPermuteIterator(long N) throws Exception {
        if (N <= 0 || N > Math.pow(2, 62)) throw new Exception("Unsupported size: " + N);
        this.N = N;
        m = (long) Math.pow(2, Math.ceil(Math.log(N) / Math.log(2)));
        next = seed = new Random().nextInt((int) Math.min(N, Integer.MAX_VALUE));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        RandomPermuteIterator r = new RandomPermuteIterator(100);
        while (r.hasMoreElements()) System.out.print(r.nextElement() + " ");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasMoreElements() {
        return hasNext;
    }

    @Override
    public Long nextElement() {
        next = (a * next + c) % m;
        while (next >= N) next = (a * next + c) % m;
        if (next == seed) hasNext = false;
        return  next;
    }
}
```